# Hints regarding a "conjecture" about Pythagorean triples in a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

My professor made the following "conjecture" in our elementary number theory course:

$$\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{F}_p^3 : x^2 + y^2 = z^2\} = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{F}_p^3 : x = 2st, y = s^2 - t^2, z = s^2 + t^2, s, t \in \mathbb{F}_p\}.$$

I put it in quotations because he personally did not know if it was true or false, not that it's any kind of conjecture in the mathematical community. We have both been working on it and haven't made much progress. I believe that it is true because I have tested numerous random large primes in SAGE, and it was true in all cases. So I attempted to prove it.

As you see below, I'm breaking it down into four cases, none of which seem particularly fruitful.

Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless $p=2$, it ought to follow from the rational parametrization of the "circle" $x^2+y^2=1$ working over $\Bbb Q$. If you look at the proof that the circle can be parametrized by 
$$x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\,, \qquad y = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\,,$$
and substitute $u=t/s$, $s,t\in\Bbb Z$, you'll get integers $x,y,z$ as in your formula satisfying $x^2+y^2=z^2$. This algebra should work just fine over any field, so long as the characteristic isn't $2$ ... I think. :)